# HTML forms for (repeated=True) properties

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do I handle value(s) from a html form which is using a `repeated=True` property?

For example, I have this *ndb.Model*:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    genre = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
```

With this form inside the *new-book.html*:

```
<form method="post">

    Book Title: <input type="text" name="title">
    Book Genre: <input type="text" name="genre">

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Is it appropriate to use the `type="text"` input? Do I ask users to *"separate each genre with a comma"*, and then process this myself in the handler? What is the best practice for handling this type of property in html forms?

(I've asked a related question here about handling repeated StructuredProperty: [Google AppEngine: Form handling 'repeated' StructuredProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025241/google-appengine-form-handling-repeated-structuredproperty))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good bare-bones solution is to yes, do a comma-separated approach. Obviously not the most elegant, but it'll work.

`book.genre = self.request.get("genre").split(",")`

Alternatively, if you repeat the form input field, you can reuse the same input 'name' and retrieve all of the values via `self.request.get_all()` in your handler. ([See the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get))

`book.genre = self.request.get_all("genre")`

My favored approach is handling data over AJAX via JSON, which would remove the need for any handling other than creating an array of values in JavaScript.

```
import json
form_data = json.loads(form_data)
book.genre = form_data['genre']
```

Comment: When I use `self.request.get_all('genre')`, it returns the result in a list. Example: `[u'horror, comedy, romance']`. I can then split it like this: `genres = [u'horror, comedy, romance'].split(', ')`, and this returns `[u'horror', u'comedy', u'romance']`. Why is there a `u` prepending the value? I should ideally store this as `['horror', 'comedy', 'romance']` right? Sorry if this is too simple; this is my first time programming.

Comment: The u indicates unicode string :). Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values . You should be fine storing it in the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of the possible genres beforehand then a group of checkboxes or a select box would also work well.