# Google App Engine: Preserving 'checkbox' user input

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, checkbox, app-engine-ndb

Consider this new-food.html:

```
<form>
  <h2>Food Name</h2>
  <input type="text" name="food" value="%(foodname)s">

  <h2>Sides:<h2>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides"  value="with_salad"> With Salad
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides"  value="with_fries"> With Fries

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On submit, it will create a *food* entity with these items saved `['apple', 'mango']`. What happens when we want to edit this entity? The `%(foodname)s` will preserve the *Food Name text field*, but how do we preserve the *checkbox* fields uploading of the page, like this:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides"  value="with_fries" checked> With Fries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app engine Python you can use Jinja2 for server side templating:

```
<form>
  <h2>Food Name</h2>
  <input type="text" name="food" value="{{ foodname }}">

  <h2>Sides:<h2>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides"  value="with_salad" {% if sides == "with_salad" %}checked{% endif %}> With Salad
  <input type="checkbox" name="sides"  value="with_fries" {% if sides == "with_fries" %}checked{% endif %}> With Fries

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

See the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: Thank you @voscausa. From your profile, I have noticed that you are very knowledegable in GAE. If you wouldn't mind, I would love your help in this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025241/google-appengine-form-handling-repeated-structuredproperty. I am hoping to build a much needed jobs marketplace for a developing country.